# Why is my C Yacc/lex calculator not parsing correctly?

Tags: c, calculator, yacc, lex

I have built a calculator using C Yacc and Lex that can store 26 variables for the letters of the alphabet. Here's what it is supposed to look like:

```
Example Input:
a = 55-3;
b = c = a-42;
a+b*c;
c = 6;
a = b;
a = 10000;
b = 100000;
a*b;
a*b*10;
c/d;
d/c;
^D

Example Output:
52
10
152
6
0
10000
100000
1000000000
overflow
dividebyzero
0
```

Here are some examples where my code doesn't work properly:

```
$ ./cexpr
a = 7;
7

b = 6;
6

c = a = b;
6

a = 8;
8

(a + b);
14

a + b;
syntax error

Invalid expression.
$ ./cexpr
4 + 5;
9

a = 6 + 1 * 5;
11

(a + 1);
overflow
11

a + 1;
syntax error

Invalid expression.
$ ./cexpr
6 * 3;
18

6 & 90;
2

4 >> 6;
0

8 ^ 3;
1

85 + 6;
91

8 / 4;
syntax error

Invalid expression.
```

I've set up my program to parse using operator precedence by creating a number of nonterminals.

Lex:

```
    %{
    #include "y.tab.h"
%}

%{
    void yyerror(char *);
%}

%%
[0-9]+      { sscanf(yytext, "%d", &yylval.num);
            return NUM; }
[a-z]       { yylval.num = *yytext - 'a';
            return VAR; }
"dump"      { yylval.string=strdup(yytext);
            return DUMP; }
"clear"     { yylval.string=strdup(yytext);
            return CLEAR; }
[ /t]+      {}
.           { return yytext[0]; }
```

Yacc:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
%}

%union {
  int num;
  char *string;
}

%token <num> NUM
%token <num> VAR
%token <string> DUMP
%token <string> CLEAR
%type <num> expr1
%type <num> expr2
%type <num> expr3
%type <num> expr4
%type <num> expr5
%type <num> expr6
%type <num> expr7
%type <num> expr8
%type <num> assign
%type <num> value

%{
    void yyerror(char *);
    int yylex();
    int alph[26];
    int INT_MAX = 2147483649;
    void val_dump();
    void val_clear();
%}

%%
commands:
        |   commands command
        ;

command :   assign ';'      { printf("%d\n", $1); }
        |   DUMP ';'        { val_dump(); }
        |   CLEAR ';'       { val_clear(); }
        ;

assign  :   VAR '=' assign  { alph[$1] = $3; $$ = alph[$1]; }
        |   VAR '+' '=' assign  { alph[$1] += $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
        |   VAR '-' '=' assign  { alph[$1] -= $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
        |   VAR '*' '=' assign  { alph[$1] *= $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
        |   VAR '/' '=' assign  { alph[$1] /= $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
        |   VAR '%' '=' assign  { alph[$1] %= $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
        |   VAR '<' '<' '=' assign  { alph[$1] <<= $5; $$ = alph[$1]; }
        |   VAR '>' '>' '=' assign  { alph[$1] >>= $5; $$ = alph[$1]; }
        |   VAR '&' '=' assign  { alph[$1] &= $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
        |   VAR '^' '=' assign  { alph[$1] ^= $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
        |   expr1           { $$ = $1; }
        ;

// The higher the number the higher the precedence.
// Parenthesis is alwaays first.

expr1   :   expr1 '|' expr1 { $$ = $1 | $3; }
        |   '(' expr1 ')'   { $$ = $2; }
        |   expr2           { $$ = $1; }
        ;

expr2   :   expr2 '^' expr2 { $$ = ($1 | $3) & !( $1 & $3); }
        |   '(' expr1 ')'   { $$ = $2; }
        |   expr3           { $$ = $1; }
        ;

expr3   :   expr3 '&' expr3 { $$ = $1 & $3; }
        |   '(' expr1 ')'   { $$ = $2; }
        |   expr4           { $$ = $1; }
        ;

expr4   :   expr4 '<' '<' expr4 { $$ = $1 << $4; }
        |   expr4 '>' '>' expr4 { $$ = $1 >> $4; }
        |   '(' expr1 ')'   { $$ = $2; }
        |   expr5           { $$ = $1; }
        ;

expr5   :   expr5 '+' expr5 { if ($1 <= INT_MAX - $3) $$ = $1 + $3; else printf("overflow\n"); }
        |   expr5 '-' expr5 { $$ = $1 - $3; }
        |   '(' expr1 ')'   { $$ = $2; }
        |   expr6           { $$ = $1; }
        ;

expr6   :   expr6 '*' expr6 { if ($1 <= INT_MAX / $3) $$ = $1 * $3; else printf("overflow\n"); }
        |   expr6 '/' expr6 { if ($3 != 0) $$ = $1 / $3; else printf("dividebyzero\n"); }
        |   expr6 '%' expr6 { if ($3 != 0) $$ = $1 % $3; else printf("dividebyzero\n"); }
        |   '(' expr1 ')'   { $$ = $2; }
        |   expr7           { $$ = $1; }
        ;

expr7   :   '-' expr7       { $$ = - $2; }
        |   '(' expr1 ')'   { $$ = $2; }
        |   expr8           { $$ = $1; }
        ;

expr8   :   '~' expr8       { $$ = ~ $2; }
        |   '(' expr1 ')'   { $$ = $2; }
        |   value           { $$ = $1; }
        ;

value   :   NUM             { $$ = $1; }
        |   VAR             { $$ = alph[$1]; }
        ;

%%

int main()
{
    if (yyparse())
        printf("\nInvalid expression.\n");
    else
        printf("\nCalculator off.\n");
}

void yyerror(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

void val_dump(){
    char c = 'a';
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("%c: %d\n", (c++), alph[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm failing to understand exactly what's going on here.

Comment: Even though you have an instance of `(c++)` in your code, it is not really C++.

Comment: Please pick one of C and C++. Questions that do not specify which programming language they are about are closed.

Comment: I don't know if you are already aware of it, but Yacc has another, much simpler, mechanism to express operator precedence and associativity instead of doing it in the grammar with all those expr1, expr2 and so on. You can declare precedence and associativity using %left, %right and %nonassoc.

Answer (score 1):

The `INT_MAX` problem doesn't account for all of these errors. The main problem is that your grammar is all over the place. I'm surprised it isn't ambiguous. Please look up the grammar from most any standard language. For example, parentheses should only appear in one production, in this case `expr8.` And all these `expr1, expr2, ...` non-terminals have standard names: logical-expression, and-expression, or-expression, expression, term, factor, primary.

```
// The higher the number, the higher the precedence.
```

No. In this grammar as you wrote it, the higher the number the *lower* the precedence.

```
// Parenthesis is always first
```

It shouldn't be. It should appear almost last in the usual order of writing productions, which is lowest-to-highest precedence.

Your grammar should look something like this:

```
commands
    : /* empty */
    | commands command
    ;

command
    : assign ';'      { printf("%d\n", $1); }
    | DUMP ';'        { val_dump(); }
    | CLEAR ';'       { val_clear(); }
    ;

assign 
    : VAR '=' assign  { alph[$1] = $3; $$ = alph[$1]; }
    | VAR '+' '=' assign  { alph[$1] += $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
    | VAR '-' '=' assign  { alph[$1] -= $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
    | VAR '*' '=' assign  { alph[$1] *= $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
    | VAR '/' '=' assign  { alph[$1] /= $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
    | VAR '%' '=' assign  { alph[$1] %= $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
    | VAR '<' '<' '=' assign  { alph[$1] <<= $5; $$ = alph[$1]; }
    | VAR '>' '>' '=' assign  { alph[$1] >>= $5; $$ = alph[$1]; }
    | VAR '&' '=' assign  { alph[$1] &= $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
    | VAR '^' '=' assign  { alph[$1] ^= $4; $$ = alph[$1]; }
    | logical-expression           { $$ = $1; }
    ;

logical-expression
    : and-expression
    | logical-expression '|' and-expression { $$ = $1 | $3; }
    ;

and-expression
    : xor-expression
    | and-expression '&' xor-expression           { $$ = $1; }
    ;

xor-expression
    : shift-expression
    | xor-expression '^' shift-expression { $$ = $1 ^ $3; }
    ;

shift-expression
    : expression
    | shift-expresion '<' '<' expression { $$ = $1 << $3; }
    | shift-expresion '>' '>' expression { $$ = $1 >> $3; }
    ;

expression
    : term
    | expression '+' term { if ($1 <= INT_MAX - $3) $$ = $1 + $3; else printf("overflow\n"); }
    | expression '-' term { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    ;

term
    : factor
    | term '*' factor { if ($1 <= INT_MAX / $3) $$ = $1 * $3; else printf("overflow\n"); }
    | term '/' factor { if ($3 != 0) $$ = $1 / $3; else printf("dividebyzero\n"); }
    | term '%' factor { if ($3 != 0) $$ = $1 % $3; else printf("dividebyzero\n"); }
    ;

factor
    : primary
    | '-' primary { $$ = -$2; }
    /* And why not have primary '+'? It costs nothing. */
    | '+' primary { $$ = $2; }
    | '~' primary { $$ = ~ $2; }
    ;

primary
    : value
    | '(' logical-expression ')'   { $$ = $2; }
    ;

value
    : NUM             { $$ = $1; }
    | VAR             { $$ = alph[$1]; }
    ;
```

E&OE

Comment: It would be informative for the user to know what part of OP's grammar makes `a+1` an error while `1+a` works.

Comment: @ring0 Too broad. This is StackOverflow, not Compiler Construction 101. Sometimes you just have to learn the right way. I did. And as a matter of fact `1+a` doesn't even appear in the question. I'm satisfied with my contribution as it is, and I'm pretty certain it solves not only the errors that do appear in the question *but also* the one you mention *and* anything else you want to dream up after the event as well. But I haven't tested it. If you have an answer of your own to contribute, don't let me stop you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your definitions, it is probably not the only cause for the problems, but

```
int INT_MAX = 2147483649;
```

Should be

```
int INT_MAX = 2147483647;
```

It is actually incorrect to assume `int` to be 32 bits or in your case *at least* 32 bits, but if you are going to assume that, at least use the correct value.

As rightly mentioned by FUZxxl, you should not redefine `INT_MAX` yourself. Either use a different name or include `<limits.h>` and remove your definition.

Comment: You should actually not define `INT_MAX` at all, that's undefined behaviour. Include `limits.h` to get a correct definition of `INT_MAX`.

Comment: It is not undefined behaviour, but it will probably fail to compile if `<limits.h>` is included.  I agree with FUZxxl: you should either use a different name or include `<limits.h>` and remove your definition.

Comment: Okay, I just looked again. §7.1.4 ¶1 #3 only reserves macros if the corresponding header is included, which is pretty sensible (declaring or defining reserved identifiers is undefined behaviour as per §7.1.4 ¶2). This rule seems to be motivated by backwards-compatibility. For example, people who define their own `bool` type are not causing undefined behaviour unless they include `stdbool.h`.

Comment: Surely it's curious that it even compiled?

Comment: @EJP: it should compile if `<limits.h>` is not included.  `INT_MAX` is not a predefined identifier.  It is specified to be a macro defined in `<limits.h>`

Comment: But surely an integer overflow should have been reported?

Comment: @EJP: the statement `int INT_MAX = 2147483649;` attempts to initialize `INT_MAX` with a constant value that is larger than the *real* `INT_MAX`.  Most compilers do not warn by default about this implicit narrowing conversion from `long` or `unsigned` to `int`.

Comment: And that's what I find curious.